# Configure owncloud on EC2 for downloading large files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, owncloud

I have an EC2 instance running Owncloud 10.0.10

The files are stored in an `S3` bucket.
Files up to 200-300MB works fine.

However, for large files **(+1GB)**, it is impossible to download them, it keeps processing for a while, and then I get a 500 error after a few minutes processing.

I have tried changing my EC2 instance size, got to the x4large one (64GB ram and 16 cores), and increased the `memory_limit` on my `php.ini` to near to this value. Yet, the download cannot even start, I click on it, it keeps processing and then I get this error.

Any idea what can I do to fix it?

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires big file chunking for S3. This is implemented in Nextcloud. Not sure about owncloud. Maybe you should give this a try.

Comment: Changing to NextCloud did the job, or at least fixed this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I assume it does some processing when downloading the files. Maybe it generates video previews or something? There should be a way in Owncloud to disable this processing.

Also it looks like S3 can be used as the OwnCloud primary storage - that way you may not need to download the files to your EC2 first: [**Amazon S3 as OwnCloud primary storage**](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/10.1/admin_manual/enterprise/external_storage/s3_swift_as_primary_object_store_configuration.html)

Hope that helps :)